# itext 7 Tab order - Failed

Tags: itext7

Files that are supposed to demonstrate the support UA in iText7 and provided as a part of Jump Start Tutorial, fail to pass Accessibility Full Check.  This test is available within Adobe Acrobat Pro.

I tested the following files:
cmp_quick_brown_fox_PDFUA.pdf and cmp_united_states_PDFA-3a.pdf

What API can be used to make them compliant?  Is there a plan to fix this issue?
Thanks for your help.

[This error as demonstrated by Adobe Acrobat Pro](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SxdSO.png)

[and here also](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ofk76.png)

Comment: Please show enough code to reproduce the issue.

Comment: cmp_united_states_PDFA-3a.pdf passes preflight for 3B, 3A and 3U for me

Comment: I have updated the question to better illustrate the problem.  There is no custom code here; it is all iText examples as provided.  I appreciate your help.

Answer (score 1):

To assure PDF/UA compliance, before calling document.close() I call a method I wrote which sets the tabs property on each generated page to follow the document structure:

```
void setTabs(PdfDocument pdfDocument) {

    int numPages = pdfDocument.getNumberOfPages();

    for (int i = 1; i <= numPages; i++) {
        PdfPage page = pdfDocument.getPage(i);
        page.put(new PdfName("Tabs"), PdfName.S);
    }
}
```

For example:

```
String dest = ("C:\temp\result.pdf");
PdfWriter writer = new PdfWriter(dest, new WriterProperties().addXmpMetadata());
PdfDocument pdfDoc = new PdfDocument(writer);
Document document = new Document(pdfDoc, PageSize.LETTER, false);

pdfDoc.setTagged();
pdfDoc.getCatalog().setViewerPreferences(new PdfViewerPreferences().setDisplayDocTitle(true));
pdfDoc.getCatalog().setLang(new PdfString("en-US"));
PdfDocumentInfo info = pdfDoc.getDocumentInfo();
info.setTitle("The Title");

Paragraph p = new Paragraph();       
p.add(new Text("Hello World");
document.add(p);

setTabs(pdfDoc);
document.close()
```

I found that I have to set the immediateFlush property to false when creating the Document object in order to be able to iterate through the pages before closing the document.

Answer (score 0):

One way to fix the problem for `7.0.1` and earlier versions is to manually set `/Tabs` key to value `/S` as suggested.

In `7.0.2` and on this problem is fixed and by default you would get tagged documents that comply with tab order check.

By the way, from `7.0.2` on you can also use `setTabOrder` convenience method on `PdfPage` to change the tab order.

Comment: Please note that as of the date of this answer `7.0.2` version is not publicly released yet, but it will be released really soon, and the answer will be useful for persons who come across this question later and want to upgrade.